# How do I stop panning on a monitor that supports a specific resolution?

Tags: windows-xp, multiple-monitors, display, resolution, windows-registry

I've been battling this for a few days now. Any and all help is appreciated.

I have a planar monitor with a native res of 1280x1024. At one point, I had used PowerStrip to override "something" and set the res to 1600x1200, and it worked great.
I then installed new intel graphics drivers for my 86895g (or w/e model) video card, which screwed up whatever settings I had. If I set it to 1600x1200 this time, it would set the res correctly, but give me a 1280x1024 viewport and the screen would pan when the mouse got to the edges of the screen. Absolutely not useful. Ok, so I was limited to 1280x1024 now. W/e.

Now...enter new video card with two video ports. I have two monitors now and the latest nVidia drivers. I decide to try to get dual 1600x1200 going...ended up screwing the original monitor up so much now that it's at 1280x1024, with a 1024x768 viewport and panning! Absolutely not usable now.
So what I need, and I can't seem to find on any forums, is help doing one or more of the following:

- Clearing out all monitor/edid info out of the windows registry without corrupting the registry.
- Actually correctly override the EDID values and get my sweet res back.
- Some other way of getting back to at least dual 1280x1024 with NO panning.

Note: My device manager shows 4 monitors for some reason. My registry shows entries for all sorts of monitors that have been hooked up to the machine over the years. It's making it difficult to debug.

Experience with PowerStrip would be helpful. I've been mucking with Phoenix EDID designer and MonInfo as well, but I'm stumbling around in the dark with these.

- Windows XP SP2
- nVidia GeForce 6200
- nVidia drivers: v258.96
- Monitor: Planar PL 1910M

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well...I didn't really solve it, but I restarted and switched the monitors (one was plugged into dvi and the other vga) and they both came up with the settings reset. Multiple restarts before hand didn't do it, but that was enough to clear whatever garbage I started with PowerStrip.